# Do angular need 3rd party state management like NGRX, NGXS, Akita?

Tags: angular7, angular-state-managmement

Do we need state managers like NGRX, NGXS, Akita in angular 4+ meanwhile we already have observables in framework.

Answer (score 3):

Angular is already good at everything a state management system would give you.

States can be managed with *singleton* or *dependency injection* services in your Angular application: just create a service that manages your application state and inject it into your components.

If your application is going to be extremely large and complex  enough to justify it, Akita is elegant in its simplicity.